# Самописный аналог функции strstr для поиска в C-строках

Tags: c++

Написал аналог функции поиска первого вхождения шаблона в текст. В качестве первого параметра функция принимает текст (C-style строка), в которой нужно искать шаблон. В качестве второго параметра строку-шаблон (C-style строка), которую нужно найти. Функция возвращает позицию первого вхождения строки-шаблона, если он присутствует в строке (считаем с 0), и -1, если шаблона в тексте нет.

Можно ли придумать такие входные данные, которые эта функция не сможет обработать?

```
 int strstr_1(const char *text, const char *pattern) {
    if (strlen_1(text) < strlen_1(pattern)) return -1;//проверка длины
    if (*text == '\0' && *pattern == '\0') return 0; // если пустые строки  
    else if (*pattern != '\0'&& *text == '\0') return -1; 
    else if (*text != '\0' && *pattern == '\0') return 0;
    bool temp = true;
    const char *t = text;
    const char*p = pattern;
    int i = 0;
    for (; *text; text++) {
        t = text; p = pattern; i++;
        while (*p && *t) {
            temp = true;
            if (*p != *t) { temp = false;  break; }
            p++; t++;
        }
        if (temp) return i-1;
    }

    return -1;
 }

// эти случаю обрабатываются правильно
cout << "1) " << strstr_1("some", "somesome") << endl; // -1
cout << "2) " << strstr_1("", "some") << endl; // -1
cout << "3) " << strstr_1("", "") << endl; // 0
cout << "4) " << strstr_1("some", "some") << endl; // 0
cout << "5) " << strstr_1("asfasfasfasf", "asf") << endl; // 0
cout << "6) " << strstr_1("asfasfasfasf", "sfa") << endl; // 1
cout << "7) " << strstr_1("My name", " ") << endl; // 2
cout << "8) " << strstr_1("My name", "My") << endl; // 0
cout << "9) " << strstr_1("My name", "me") << endl; // 5
cout << "10) " << strstr_1("aaaaaaaf", "aaf") << endl; // 5
cout << "11) " << strstr_1(" ", "") << endl; // 0
cout << "12) " << strstr_1(" ", " ") << endl; // 0
cout << "13) " << strstr_1("", " ") << endl; // -1
cout << "14) " << strstr_1("\0", "\0") << endl; // 0
cout << "15) " << strstr_1("...my name...", "mye") << endl; // -1
cout << "16) " << strstr_1("...my name...mye", "mye") << endl; //13
cout << "17) " << strstr_1("mmmmy enammmmmye..mye!", "mye") << endl; //13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, например aaab и  aabb выдаёт 1 при ожидаемом -1.

Ошибка в `while (*p && *t)` и `if (temp) return` помогло бы `if (temp && (*t==0)` иначе нет проверки что закончился именно шаблон а не сама строка.

А вообще какой практический смысл менять реализацию strstr на работающую за O(nm) да ещё и "грязную" (например функции memcmp и strcmp работают на ассемблерном уровне и значительно быстрее лобовых циклов (не берём в расчёт умный компилятор)).

Если вам критична скорость рекомендую почитать о алгоритмах Кнута — Морриса — Пратта (КМП) о z-функции, конечном автомате или аналогичном (сложность O(n+m)).

Comment: спасибо большое за подсказку! 

Это учебное задание, так что практического смысла эта функция не будет иметь.